# unable to run a batch file if I place the code inside any if conditions

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which will be placed inside the if else statement i.e., if the condition is true it should create a batch file and run that batch file and if the condition is false the else part should create another batch file.
The below code is not working i.e., it is not creating the batch file.

```
function saveFilePP() {
  loc_ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
  var Path = document.getElementById("path").value;
  var username = "hduser1";
  if (Type1 == "DIRECTORY") {
    var blob = new Blob(["C:\\Users\\Nandini\\Desktop\\Plink\\plink.exe " +
      username + "@" + loc_ip + " -pw 123 hadoop fs -rm -r /" + Path + ""
    ], {
      type: "text/plain;charset=ANSI"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "delete.bat");
  } else {
    var blob = new Blob(["C:\\Users\\Nandini\\Desktop\\Plink\\plink.exe " +
      username + "@" + loc_ip + " -pw 123 hadoop fs -rm /" + Path + ""
    ], {
      type: "text/plain;charset=ANSI"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "delete.bat");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider checking your code or even running it through a validator, before posting it to tell us it didn't work? The code you have posted looks awful to me, you should also try to follow a better formatting/indentaion style.

Comment: FileSaver.js implements the saveAs() and the delete.bat gets saved in downloads only